# Sorting names with numbers correctly

Tags: c++, sorting, predicate, string-comparison

For sorting item names, I want to support numbers correctly. i.e. this:

```
1 Hamlet
2 Ophelia
...
10 Laertes
```

instead of

```
1 Hamlet
10 Laertes
2 Ophelia
...
```

**Does anyone know of a comparison functor that already supports that?**
(i.e. a predicate that can be passed to `std::sort`)

I basically have two patterns to support: Leading number (as above), and number at end, similar to explorer:

```
Dolly
Dolly (2)
Dolly (3)
```

(I guess I could work that out: compare by character, and treat numeric values differently. However, that would probably break unicode collaiton and whatnot)

Comment: `std::sort` doesn't know anything about Unicode, so you won't break that. It's the predicate that needs to deal with it properly. You probably should not break it down by character, but tokenize the string and then sort the tokens.

Comment: I have no plans to break std::sort :) Good idea comparing/collating the segments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's called alphanumeric sorting.
Check out this link: [The Alphanum Algorithm](http://www.davekoelle.com/alphanum.html)

Comment: Thanks! 
It doesn't collate segments (rather, compare char-by-char), and doesn't correctly handle numbers exceeding unsigned long, but it's a good drop-in replacement.

Answer (score 0):

i think u can use a pair object and then make vector > and then sort this vector.
Pairs are compared based on their first elements. So, this way you can get the sort you desire.